# Use Windows environment variables in Sublime Text settings files

Tags: environment-variables, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a need to reference Windows environment variables from within Sublime Text 2 settings files (Package-Name.sublime-settings files), specifically `%APPDATA%` and `%TMP%`

Is this possible, and if so, how?

For example, here is a line from one package setting, which needs to work on multiple users, so with different usernames:

```
"backup_dir": "C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\SublimeBackup"
```

As an example, here is a problem I just had: I have an install of Sublime Text 2 which runs from multiple computers (i.e. I copy its data around to keep settings etc. up to date between multiple installs), but I have the below command:

```
{ "caption": "Backup to Server (Local to Server)", "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["local-to-server.cmd"] } },
```

Unfortunately, the file "local-to-server.cmd" is relative to the currently opened file in Sublime Edit, so this command rarely works. What I need is:

```
{ "caption": "Backup to Server (Local to Server)", "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\local-to-server.cmd"] } },
```

Or some similar way of referencing a common location that I can then build a relative path from.

Comment: This would (right now) have to be implemented at the plugin level. I don't think the default packages include anything that needs variable expansion (though I could be wrong). If that's the case, you probably want to make a feature request for the specific plugin.

Comment: Is there a way to make a plugin such that variable expansion can occur in other plugins? I require this in more than one plugin/place.

Or a way to specify a specific variable with a specific value that I can use in multiple settings files?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The load settings call that is used to get these settings passes the file contents directly to the calling method. The closest you could probably get is having the base files live externally, then run a script when you move to each machine to substitute the values that you want.

Comment: @skuroda That's just wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @schlamar for the correction on settings. I didn't realize they persisted across the session. All my plugins use them locally, and I don't do any modification to them but that's good to know. Here's a plugin to expand the variables when ST loads. Should work in both ST2 and ST3.

```
import os
import sublime

VERSION = int(sublime.version())

def expand_settings():
    expand_settings = {
        "<setting file names>": [
            "<setting keys to expand>"
        ]
    }
    for filename, setting_keys in expand_settings.items():
        s = sublime.load_settings(filename)
        for key in setting_keys:
            value = s.get(key)
            s.set(key, os.path.expandvars(value))

def plugin_loaded():
    expand_settings()

if VERSION < 3006:
    expand_settings()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a Sublime Text 2 plug-in for this? I've tried it by myself but i failed because of my missing python knowledge. I've copypasted your code into a py-file and i'm gettting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` when I start ST2 and the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Did you substitue <settings file names> and <setting keys to expand> with appropriate values? Guessing this could easily be expanded into a generic plugin, reading settings files and properties from the file system too.

Comment: Yes, I set the values but maybe I'm doing it wrong:
`expand_settings = {
    "HOMEPATH": [
        "C:\\Users\\john.doe\\"
    ]
}`
Actually I'm searching for a plugin, which is reading windows variables like %HOMEPATH%, so that I can use them in other plugin settings.

Answer (score 1):

@skuroda is wrong in his comment. Setting changes are persistent across plugins and multiple `load_settings` calls. Simple test case:

```
s = sublime.load_settings('Preferences.sublime-settings')
s.set('test', 'x')
s = sublime.load_settings('Preferences.sublime-settings')
print (s.get('test'))  # prints x
```

If you split this across two plugins it will still print x (assuming the setting plugin runs before the printing plugin).

So you can load and re-write some paths with `os.path.expandvars` which will be persistent for the current session.